# Testing multible combinations

Tags: java, combinations

First of all I want to say, that I looked online for a possible or similar solution but did not find anything, might have been looking for the wrong keywords but please excuse my rather simple question.

However, currently I am trying to implement a java function that - on an input of an integer (e.g. 10) gives me every possible solutions on how to divide this by 2 or 1. 
And I literally have no clue on how to even start, as there is no pattern to it or anything that I have done is relatable.

However this is an old exam from my professor, so there is a good and short solution I am just not seeing.

Thank you very much for your help and time :)

edit:

The method I am trying to imlement would look as follows:

```
static void possibilities (int i){ }
```

I would be able to give an integer (3 for example) and then as output (through Sys.out) all possibilities of all possible combinations of 1 and 2's, for example for 3:

```
(1,1,1)
(2,1)
(1,2)
```

Or for 2:

```
(1,1)
(2)
```

Comment: I would apprechiate it greatly if bevore downvoting this post you could comment on it, so I can improve future questions :)

Comment: "every possible solutions on how to divide this by 2 or 1" For example?

Comment: Exactly, for example for 3: (1,1,1) (1,2) (2,1)

Comment: that's not division, that's addition...

Comment: well yeah I recon it can be viewed as addition aswell... exactly :)

Comment: How that can division is viewed as addition?

Comment: Well my concept on how to go at  this is to divide 3 by 2 as often as possible and then the rest by 1 until 0 is reached, that is why i thought of division (of course this doesnt make much sense as it is just the optimal solution)

Comment: But another possibility of going at this problem is to add 1 and 2 in all ossible ways until that integer is reached, that is how addition and division (in my opinion) are both possible solutions...

Comment: This is "easy": generate the 1-set then do all possible 1+1

Comment: but you can divide a number by 1 an infinite number of times...

Comment: @RC i don't exactly get what you mean, that would just give me how often 1 fits into the given integer wouldn't it?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz In my mind I would always subtract 1 when I divided it, however that was just and idea...

Comment: 5 = 1,1,1,1,1, using the first two 1, 1+1=2 so 2,1,1,1, using the 1 at index 1 and 2 => 1,2,1,1, etc (note this is a naive approach)

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz the more I think about the less my initial thought makes sense... true that addition would be the way to go i think

Comment: @RC. makes sense to me... thank you I will try that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think would work:

say the input is 5 so the very 1st combination will be: (1,1,1,1,1) right? now we add the first two number so  it is (2,1,1,1)  and store it in a string i.e. "2111" now we find all the permutations of this string (code 4 this is available), now we add the next 1,1 pair so it will look like (2,2,1) i.e "221" and again same process of permutations.

We keep repeating this till the string has just one '1' present or no '1' present, try checking for the number 4, same thing.

Comment: Thank you for that feedback, I will edit my post accordingly

Comment: I hope I could improve my question in a way that it is now understandable? ;)

Comment: yes :). Here is what I think would work: say the input is 5 so the very 1st combination will be: (1,1,1,1,1) right? now we add the first two number so  it is (2,1,1,1)  and store it in a string i.e. "2111" now we find all the permutations of this string (code 4 this is available), now we add the next 1,1 pair so it will look like (2,2,1) i.e "221" and again same process of permutations. We keep repeating this till the string has just one '1' present or no '1' present, try checking for the number 4, same thing. It's a bit late here so ill try to send code in the morning, u can try till then ;)